# Show that $h(y)=\inf_{x:g(x)\leq y} f(x)$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose that $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is convex and $f,g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are convex. Show that $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ such that
\begin{align}
h(y)=\inf_{x:g(x)\leq y} f(x)
\end{align}
is convex.

Any hints?

Comment: Shouldn’t $h$ map from $\Bbb{R}$, not $\Bbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Sorry about that - fixed it.

Comment: Okay, if I'm more explicit: $h(y)=\inf_{x\in\{\bar{x}:g(\bar{x})\leq y\}} f(x)$. Does this resolve your issue?

Comment: Ignore my last, deleted comment. Sorry.

Comment: What have you tried by just using the definition of $f,g$ convexity?

Comment: I hoped not to resort to that

Comment: @BasicUser Why? A bit of sweat is probably useful.

Comment: Thought there might be a short elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $y_1,y_2\in\mathbb R$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$. I present a proof only for the case when both $h(y_1)$ and $h(y_2)$ are finite, leaving the infinite-valued cases to you.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and find $x_1,x_2\in X$ such that

- $g(x_1)\leq y_1$,
- $g(x_2)\leq y_2$,
- $h(y_1)\leq f(x_1)<h(y_1)+\varepsilon$, and
- $h(y_2)\leq f(x_2)<h(y_2)+\varepsilon$.

Now the convexity of $g$ implies that $$g(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\leq\lambda g(x_1)+(1-\lambda)g(x_2)\leq\lambda y_1+(1-\lambda)y_2.$$ Therefore, since $f$ is also a convex function,
\begin{align*}
h(\lambda y_1+(1-\lambda)y_2)&=\inf\big\{f(\hat x)\,\big|\,\hat x\in X\text{ and }g(\hat x)\leq\lambda y_1+(1-\lambda)y_2\big\}\\&\leq f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\\&\leq \lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)f(x_2)\\&<\lambda h(y_1)+(1-\lambda) h(y_2)+\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Take $\varepsilon\downarrow 0$.